# CUDA: identifier "cudaMemGetInfo" is undefined

Tags: cuda

To estimate how much data the program may process in one kernel launch i try to get some memory info with `cudaMemGetInfo()`. However, the compiler tells me this:
error: identifier "cudaMemGetInfo" is undefined

Other functions like `cudaGetDeviceProperties();` work fine. Do I have to install a certain CUDA-version? The [library description](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gd5d6772f4b2f3355078ecd6059e6aa74.html) does not contain infos about the version and so on.

EDIT: the smallest possible code. `cudaSetDevice()` generates no compiler error while `cudaMemGetInfo()` does

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main(){
   unsigned int f, t;
   cudaSetDevice(0);
   cudaMemGetInfo(&f, &t);
   return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: 
I'm on Linux using "Cuda compilation tools, release 2.0, V0.2.1221" (nvcc). 
As I tried to get the cuda driver version installed with `cudaDriverGetVersion()` the same error occured (same thing when I use the driver function `cuDriverGetVersion()`). 
It seems that the system wont let me know any detail about itself...

Comment: Did you include cuda_runtime_api.h ?

Comment: @Pavan: Until now I only included cuda.h. If I include cuda_runtime_api.h as well the error remains.

Comment: Can you post a concede repro case which can be compiled by others which demonstrates the problem? The function has been in the API since before CUDA 1.0, so something else must be wrong.

Comment: Paste the exact compiler warning please.

Comment: @Pavan: it is in the third line of my question: 'error: identifier "cudaMemGetInfo" is undefined'

Comment: @Callahan: I was slightly wrong in my initial comment here - `cuMemGetInfo` has been in the driver API forever, but the runtime API equivalent was only added in CUDA 3.0. Because you are using a truly ancient version of CUDA, you do not have access to that API call. Your initial suspicion about version proved correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the very old version of CUDA you are using, `cudaMemGetInfo` is not part of the runtime API. It has a counterpart in the driver `cuMemGetInfo`, which can be used instead. Note that using the driver API version of this call will require establishing a context first. This should work on CUDA 2.x:

```
// CUDA 2.x version
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main(){
    unsigned int f, t;
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaFree(0); // This will establish a context on the device
    cuMemGetInfo(&f, &t);
    fprintf(stdout,"%d %d\n",f/1024,t/1024);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: this answer applied to CUDA 3.0 and later:**

Your problem isn't `cudaMemGetInfo`, it is the arguments you are supplying it. I would predict that this:

```
// CUDA 3.0 or later version
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main(){
    size_t f, t;
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaMemGetInfo(&f, &t);
    return 0;
}
```

will work where your example fails. Note that `nvcc` uses a host C++ compiler to compile host code, and it will not find instances of API functions with incorrect arguments. Note that the prototype of [cudaMemGetInfo](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gd5d6772f4b2f3355078ecd6059e6aa74.html) is

```
cudaError_t cudaMemGetInfo(size_t * free, size_t * total)
```

and that the arguments should be `size_t`, which is not the same as `unsigned int` on many platforms.

Comment: This is a good point. But it does not solve the problem... I tried giving `cudaSetDevice()` a pointer instead of an integer and the compiler recognizes it: 'error: argument of type "size_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int"'

Comment: @Callahan: so you are saying that the code I posted doesn't compile for you? What compiler, OS and CUDA version are you doing this on?

Comment: Yes it does not compile displaying the same errors as before. I posted the asked informations in my question under EDIT 2.

Comment: When using the driver version of the function now the linker reports the same error: `tmpxft_00007cbb_00000000-10_test.ii:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to 'cuMemGetInfo'`

Comment: Link the driver API, add -lcuda to the compile ststement

Comment: It does compile now! Great (: But the output sais that there are 0 bytes in total and 0 bytes free... any idea?

Comment: @Callahan, It may be returning an error code which you are not catching. Check what the error is.

Comment: @Callahan: see the edit in the answer for a working example with CUDA 2.x. You might want to consider upgrade to a supported, non-deprecated version of the API at your earliest convenience.

Comment: The 0,0 results remain even if I establish a context like you supposed. Unfortunatly the admins of the machine I am working on will not upgrade in near future... If you have another tip I would be glad to hear about but I guess the upgrade should e the way of choice. Thanks for your time so far!

Comment: If that doesn't work, the CUDA installation or the toolkit you are using is broken somehow. This is no longer even tangentially related to the original question, so the is not much point in continuing,

Answer (score 1):

to fix this error:

error: argument of type "unsigned int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "size_t *".

I found from [nvidia technical report for cuda 3.2](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2/toolkit/docs/CUDA_3.2_Readiness_Tech_Brief.pdf) that:
 Driver API functions that accept or return memory sizes, such as cuMemAlloc() and cuMemGetInfo(), now use size_t for this purpose rather than unsigned int.

so you must change *.cu code, as the following lines:

Incorrect code:
 unsigned int free, total;
 cuMemGetInfo(&free, &total);

Correct code:
 size_t free, total;
 cuMemGetInfo(&free, &total);